# I am not able to post with uc browser

Tags: discussion, bug

When I attempt to answer or ask a question with my phone, the edit bar is missing; that's why I am not able to post something with my phone:
[image: this is the screen shot from my uc browser]

It still shows up on desktop view. Is this a problem with my uc browser or a site problem?

Or when I switch it to desktop view on uc browser then editing menu appears but it won't work properly.....

Comment: Have you tried using a different browser, the Android app or a desktop browser?

Comment: I don't see the UC browser in the [list of supported browsers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71208/158100) so this can hardly be a bug. At best a feature request.

Comment: Yes it is working well on chrome r desktop browser ................but plz add uc browser in supported list

Answer (score 1):

From [Which browsers are officially supported, and what else do I need?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need/71208#71208)

> we support the last two versions of the browsers that we see the vast majority of our visitors actually use.

So your browser is probably not enough used by users.

And it's possible that it's just your browser that don't implements web standards of the moment (HTML 5 , CSS3, ...)

Comment: In my above screenshot you can see clearly that editing box is not visible r found.........I am using the latest version of android uc browser10.10.0.796...............

Comment: Well as said others, does it works on others mobile browsers ? If so then your browsers is more likely to have a problem than SO.

Comment: Ohk.....thnx for your suggestion

Comment: Still wait for a diamond user to answer the question, or from one of the SE developers, there are the ones that will definitively tell you what's going on, i'm none of them. I'm just saying that if that bug is specific to that browser only, it may be hard for them to do something.

Comment: For your information I want to tell u that I am using lenovo k3note.........so,I don't think that this problem is related with my OS but maybe I am wrong.........but thnx a lot for giving me a answer......have a nice day