# What are the reasons to downvote a bug report on Meta?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, meta, bug-reporting-process

I've seen many questions tagged [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug) on Meta that have a negative score. It seems strange to me that a bug report can be good or bad, and people can agree or disagree with a bug report. What are the reasons for downvoting a bug report on Meta?

Comment: Bugs that aren't bugs. Badly written bug reports. Something nobody will ever be able to reproduce. Etc. etc.

Comment: Evidence please?

Comment: @Paulie_D http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug?sort=votes

Comment: @Paulie_D http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbug%5D+score%3A..-1+is%3Aquestion

Comment: Calling incompatibilities with unsupported browsers "bugs" also tends to yield downvotes, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326892/i-am-not-able-to-post-with-uc-browser

Comment: If you've never exclaimed "oh for crissake, I've got something better to do, deal with it" at a bug report then you're not a programmer or nobody trusts you to get out of your cubicle. Given the voting on your meta posts, the latter explanation is somewhat likely.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When it:

> ...does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful

That's the standard hover text, with no exception for bug reports.

A bug report may fall under that umbrella when:

- We can't understand what they're saying (*plz xcuze mah ngrsh*)
- The behavior is not a bug (*I got a question ban, but I deleted all my bad questions!*)

  - This generally falls under "lack of research"
- The behavior is a bug that we all know, but are tired of hearing about ([Giant S's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/63791#63791)).

  - Also may be considered "lack of research"
- The whims of individuals (voting is anonymous and they don't need to give an explanation)